# memcpy of char pointer crashes the mcu

Tags: arduino-c++

```cpp
const uint8_t RX_MSG_MAX_LENGTH = 160;
char rxPacket[RX_MSG_MAX_LENGTH];

const char *decrypt(const char *base64Text) {
  // ...
  return (char*) message;
}

const char *decryptedRes = decrypt(rxPacket);
```

`rxPacket` contains base64 encoded, encrypted data, such as `MigoG5dyDbsZmC4gh5TbAS88G8RlLJf9ase3mmzrhOUQ3awWzQkTpTzcm2ItUC/W`

`decryptedRes` contains decrypted data, such as `hub^bal^1722^voltage=3.85V^1632953599`, and does print exactly that in the serial monitor (`Serial.println(decryptedRes);`)

I want to process the decrypted data in order to get the chars after the last occurrence of `^`. In my example above, that would be `1632953599`

```cpp
        // verify checksum
        //char checker[RX_MSG_MAX_LENGTH] = "";
        char * checker = new char[strlen(decryptedRes) + 1];

        const char * pos = strrchr(decryptedRes, '^');
        if (pos != nullptr) {
          uint8_t length = pos - decryptedRes + 1; // accounts for the delimiter
          /*memcpy(checker, decryptedRes, length); // crashes the Nano and I have no idea why
          checker[length] = '\0';

          // ...
          */
        }
```

The microcontroller (Arduino Nano) crashes when I run `memcpy`. Why ?

Comment: You are using `strlen()` to obtain the length of the decrypted data.  2 questions:  Are you using one byte per character?  Did you remember to terminate the string with the null char at the end of `decrypt()`?

Comment: Can you give us enuogh code to replicate the error? We can't tell a lot of things that may be causing the error.